# Different results running batch script as administrator than running it form elevated command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, regedit

I have a script to change registry values. 
Running it from an elevated command window it changes the key ok.
Running it directly as an administrator (right click) it does nothing, same thing running it from task scheduler with elevated privileges.

Any idea why?

Code, basically it checks IP number and according to that it changes autoconfig proxy script with several option of .reg files with the different internet connection setup key.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET Target=%computername%
IF %Target%.==. ECHO Missing target!&PAUSE&GOTO :EOF
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ('PING %Target% -4 -n 1 ^| FIND "["') DO (
    SET TargetIP=%%A
    SET TargetIP
)
IF NOT DEFINED TargetIP ECHO NO IP found!&PAUSE&GOTO :EOF

:Compare
SET PartialIP=%TargetIP:~0,9%
IF "%PartialIP%"=="172.20.25" (
    REGEDIT /S conbae.reg
    goto :eof)
IF "%PartialIP%"=="172.20.22" (
    REGEDIT /S conbna.reg
    goto :eof)
SET PartialIP=%TargetIP:~0,6%
SET PartialIP
IF "%PartialIP%"=="172.20" (
    REGEDIT /S conweb.reg 
) ELSE (
    REGEDIT /S sinbae.reg 
)
```

Comment: Which script? show your script please.

Comment: 1. Try `reg import filename.reg`. 2. Remove/comment `@echo off`, add `pause` at the end and run the batch file both normally and elevated, compare the output in console.

Comment: That was the answer changing REGEDIT /S  to reg import. Tks!!

Comment: quoting you: >"Running it from an elevated command window it changes the key ok."
So tell us how you could have run a command that is not supposed to work on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking to run as Admin changes the working directory to the `system32` folder, and the `conbae.reg` file can't be found as it is in the current folder.

You can change `conbae.reg` to `"%~dp0conbae.reg"` in all reg files and places and it should work fine too.